# How does this split of train and evaluation data ensure there is no overlap?

Tags: tensorflow, sentiment-analysis, training-data

I am reading this sentiment classification tutorial from Tensorflow:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification

The way it splits data into train and evaluate is the following code:

```
batch_size = 32
seed = 42

raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='training', 
    seed=seed)

raw_val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='validation', 
    seed=seed)
```

Shouldn't a single call of the function text_dataset_from_directory generate the two sets? If it is called twice, does it ensure there will be no overlap between the two split sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either set a seed or set `shuffle = False` in order to make sure that you have no overlap in two sets. Here's what happens under the hood:

When subset (train-val) is provided, seed or shuffle args are checked ([Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/dataset_utils.py#L219))

```
if validation_split and shuffle and seed is None:
        raise ValueError(
            'If using `validation_split` and shuffling the data, you must provide '
            'a `seed` argument, to make sure that there is no overlap between the '
            'training and validation subset.')
```

Then, the data is reserved. ([Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/dataset_utils.py#L166))

```
num_val_samples = int(validation_split * len(samples))
if subset == 'training':
 print('Using %d files for training.' % (len(samples) - num_val_samples,))
 samples = samples[:-num_val_samples]
 labels = labels[:-num_val_samples]
elif subset == 'validation':
 print('Using %d files for validation.' % (num_val_samples,))
    samples = samples[-num_val_samples:]
    labels = labels[-num_val_samples:]
```

With the last code samples & labels restricted to the training or validation set. And since you specified **seed**, datasets is **randomized** in the **same** order.

Comment: Shouldn't it be much better to call preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory() only ONCE to return the train and validation sets? The arguments are almost the same, and the only arguments are essentially the same, except for 'training/validation'.

Comment: You call it twice because you need two seperate datasets. That's the way how it's implemented.